# What does PhISwap gate mean in Cirq?

Tags: programming, cirq, openfermion

I am currently using the Cirq pakage and when drawing the circuit structure, I constantly encountered the `PhISwap` gate, like in [here](https://quantumai.google/openfermion/tutorials/circuits_3_arbitrary_basis_trotter). What does this gate mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cirq, the `PhasedISwapPowGate` (i.e. `PhISwap`) is a fractional ISWAP conjugated by Z rotations. With phase exponent $p$ and exponent $t$, it is equivalent to the composition
$$(\text{Z}^{-p} \otimes \text{Z}^p) \text{ISWAP}^t (\text{Z}^p \otimes \text{Z}^{-p})$$
and is given by the matrix:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c & i\cdot s\cdot f & 0 \\
0 & i\cdot s \cdot f^* & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
where:
$$c = \cos(\pi \cdot t/2)$$
$$s = \sin(\pi \cdot t/2)$$
$$f = \exp(2\pi i \cdot p)$$
and star indicates complex conjugate.

The `PhasedISwapPowGate` is initialized with the following parameters:

```
phase_exponent: Union[float, sympy.Symbol] = 0.25
exponent: Union[float, sympy.Symbol] = 1.0
```

In the circuit diagram, these parameters relate to the string gate representation as:

```
0: ───PhISwap(phase_exponent)────────────
      │
1: ───PhISwap(phase_exponent)^exponent───
```

These parameters relate to the matrix representation as:

```
c = np.cos(np.pi * exponent / 2)
s = np.sin(np.pi * exponent / 2)
f = np.exp(2j * np.pi * phase_exponent)
```

Source: [phase_iswap_gate.py](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/48397d66835668c203b121e0935d88a5708502c6/cirq-core/cirq/ops/phased_iswap_gate.py)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I find that the ciruict contains `PhISwap(0.25)^-0.645`. I suppose in this case p=0.25 and t=1. However, what does the `^-0.645` mean?

Comment: @ironmanaudi Answer updated!